# Importing 'countdown' module causes error when building React app with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, countdown, rollup

I'm using the 'countdown' module in my React app, which I import like this:

```js
import countdown from 'countdown';
```

When I run the app in dev mode with Vite, everything works fine. However, when I try to build the app, I get the following error:

```
RollupError: "default" is not exported by "node_modules/.pnpm/countdown@2.6.0/node_modules/countdown/countdown.js", imported by "src/App.tsx".
```

I've tried changing the import statement to `* as countdown` instead, but then I get the following error:

```
DEFAULTS" is not exported by "node_modules/.pnpm/countdown@2.6.0/node_modules/countdown/countdown.js", imported by "src/App.tsx".
Cannot call a namespace ("countdown").
```

Here is the [MRE](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/competent-torvalds-3zpttg?file=%2FREADME.md)

Does anyone know what might be causing these errors and how I can fix them? I'm fairly new to React and Vite, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not particularly fond of this solution, it does work. Essentially, I copied the library code and type declarations (`countdown.js` and `countdown.d.ts`), turned `countdown.js` into an esm module, and made a small edit to `countdown.d.ts` to export the module.

```
let countdown: countdown.CountdownStatic;
export default countdown;
```

With these changes, everything runs and builds as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the named import

```
import * as countdown from 'countdown';
```

if this still gives you the error "cannot call a namespace", you can try accessing the functions of the countdown module like

```
const remainingTime = countdown.default(new Date(2023, 4, 20));
```

Comment: I get a type error, but if I ignore it I get this error: `"default" is not exported by "node_modules/.pnpm/countdown@2.6.0/node_modules/countdown/countdown.js"`

Comment: and when I run it in my browser I get this error `TypeError: ip is not a function`, if I use countdown.default, it replaces it with void: `TypeError: (void 0) is not a function`